# How to make SlideIn and SlideOut effects using QpropertyAnimation?

Tags: c++, qt

### My goal

I want to animate images in a slide show like this:

```
<< Animation Direction <<  
/* THIS IS EXPECTATION */  

++++++++++++++++++++--------------------
++++++++++++++++++++--------------------
+++ CURR IMAGE +++++------ NEXT IMAGE --
++++++++++++++++++++--------------------
++++++++++++++++++++--------------------
<--- VIEW --------->

++++++++++++--------------------
++++++++++++--------------------
 IMAGE +++++------ NEXT IMAGE --
++++++++++++--------------------
++++++++++++--------------------
<--- VIEW --------->

--------------------
--------------------
------ NEXT IMAGE --
--------------------
--------------------
<--- VIEW --------->
```

### What I've tried

I use two instances of `QPropertyAnimation` :

```
d->currImage      = new QLabel(ui->frmSlideshow);
d->currImage->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
d->animCurrImage  = new QPropertyAnimation(d->currImage, "geometry");

d->nextImage      = new QLabel(ui->frmSlideshow);
d->nextImage->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
d->animNextImage  = new QPropertyAnimation(d->nextImage, "geometry");

connect(d->animNextImage, SIGNAL(finished()),this, SLOT(applyBackground()));
connect(&(d->timer), SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timer_timeout()));
d->timer.start(1500);
```

On timeout I do the following:

```
QPixmap pixCurrImage;
pixCurrImage.load(d->currImagePath());
d->currImage->setPixmap(pixCurrImage);

QPixmap pixNextImage;
pixNextImage.load(d->nextImagePath());
d->nextImage->setPixmap(pixNextImage);

d->currImage->show();
d->currImage->raise();
d->currImage->setFixedSize(ui->frmSlideshow->size());

d->nextImage->show();
d->nextImage->raise();
d->nextImage->setFixedSize(ui->frmSlideshow->size());

d->animCurrImage->setDuration(500);
d->animCurrImage->setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, ui->frmSlideshow->width(), ui->frmSlideshow->height()));
d->animCurrImage->setEndValue(QRect(-1*ui->frmSlideshow->width(), 0, ui->frmSlideshow->width(), ui->frmSlideshow->height()));

d->animNextImage->setDuration(500);
d->animNextImage->setStartValue(QRect(2*ui->frmSlideshow->width(), 0, ui->frmSlideshow->width(), ui->frmSlideshow->height()));
d->animNextImage->setEndValue(QRect(0, 0, ui->frmSlideshow->width(), ui->frmSlideshow->height()));

QParallelAnimationGroup * group = new QParallelAnimationGroup(this);
group->addAnimation(d->animCurrImage);
group->addAnimation(d->animNextImage);
group->start();
```

### My problem

A small gap (approx 100px) is showing between both sliding images:

```
<< Animation Direction <<  
/* THIS IS HAPPENING*/  

++++++++++++   --------------------
++++++++++++   --------------------
 IMAGE +++++   ------ NEXT IMAGE --
++++++++++++   --------------------
++++++++++++   --------------------
<--- VIEW --------->

+++   --------------------
+++   --------------------
+++   ------ NEXT IMAGE --
+++   --------------------
+++   --------------------
<--- VIEW --------->

--------------------
--------------------
------ NEXT IMAGE --
--------------------
--------------------
<--- VIEW --------->
```

How to make it either work as expected, or achieve the desired animation in some other way?

Comment: Take a look at the [`SlideView`](https://github.com/scopchanov/flat-gui/blob/master/SlideView.h) class of my FlatGUI library and either use it as it is, or adopt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the desired animation I suggest you to take a look at the [`HorizontalSlide`](https://github.com/scopchanov/flat-gui/blob/master/HorizontalSlide.h) class of the `FlatGUI` library of widgets, written by me.

There I use [`QVariantAnimation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariantanimation.html) to create the sliding effect. Here are the essential parts of `HorizontalSlide` with regard to the animation:

```
void HorizontalSlide::start(bool slideLeft, int speed)
{
    QVariantAnimation *animation = new QVariantAnimation(this);

    m_slideLeft = slideLeft;

    m_labCurrent->show();
    m_labNext->show();

    animation->setStartValue(m_slideLeft ? 0 : m_width);
    animation->setEndValue(m_slideLeft ? m_width : 0);
    animation->setDuration(speed);
    animation->start(QVariantAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);

    connect(animation, &QVariantAnimation::valueChanged,
            this, &HorizontalSlide::onValueChanged);
    connect(animation, &QVariantAnimation::finished,
            this, &HorizontalSlide::onAnimationFinished);
}

void HorizontalSlide::onValueChanged(const QVariant &value)
{
    int n = -value.toInt(), m = m_width + n;

    if (m_slideLeft) {
        m_labCurrent->move(n, 0);
        m_labNext->move(m, 0);
    } else {
        m_labCurrent->move(m, 0);
        m_labNext->move(n, 0);
    }

    m_parentWidget->repaint();
}

void HorizontalSlide::onAnimationFinished()
{
    delete m_labCurrent;
    delete m_labNext;

    m_nextPage->show();
    m_nextPage->resize(m_parentWidget->size());

    deleteLater();
    finished();
}
```

I use the [`QVariantAnimation::valueChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariantanimation.html#valueChanged) signal to [`QWidget::move`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#move-1) a snapshot of the widgets to slide along the `x`-axis. Then the code reacts to [`QAbstractAnimation::finished`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractanimation.html#finished) signal to [`QWidget::show`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#show) and [`QWidget::resize`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#size-prop) the next page.

Provided, that you have those variables declared and initialized:

```
QWidgetList pages;  
currentIndex(-1),
nextIndex(-1),
busy(false)
```

you might use the `HorizontalSlide` in a method like this:

```
void slideToPage(int n, int speed) {
    if (busy
        || pages.isEmpty()
        || (currentIndex < 0)
        || (n == currentIndex)
        || (speed < 0))
        return;

    auto *transition = new HorizontalSlide(this);

    busy = true;

    transition->setCurrentPage(pages.at(currentIndex));
    transition->setNextPage(pages.at(n));
    transition->start(n > currentIndex, speed);

    connect(transition, &HorizontalSlide::finished,
                     [this, transition](){
        currentIndex = pages.indexOf(transition->nextPage());
        busy = false;

        currentIndexChanged(currentIndex, pages.count());
        currentPageChanged(pages.at(currentIndex)->windowTitle());
    });
}
```

You might as well add the library to your project and use its [`SlideView`](https://github.com/scopchanov/flat-gui/blob/master/SlideView.h) class.

Comment: Thanks, It was a small assignment. So I did not included whole library

Comment: @Jai, My comment, as you have confirmed, was enough to help you. However, for future reference a more comprehensive answer is needed, so I have provided that as well.

Comment: Sure, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

**LOAD IMAGES**

```
    d->currImage->setFixedSize(ui->frmSlideshow->size());
    d->currImage->move(0,0);
    QPixmap pixCurrImage;
    pixCurrImage.load(d->currImagePath());
    d->currImage->setPixmap(pixCurrImage);
    d->currImage->show();
    d->currImage->raise();

    d->nextImage->setFixedSize(ui->frmSlideshow->size());
    d->nextImage->move(ui->frmSlideshow->width(), 0); // So that  
    QPixmap pixNextImage;                             // you will not see
    pixNextImage.load(d->nextImagePath());            // glitch due 
    d->nextImage->setPixmap(pixNextImage);            // to change  
    d->nextImage->show();
    d->nextImage->raise();
```

**Animation** (Thanks to User6528273 for help)

```
    QVariantAnimation *animation = new QVariantAnimation(ui->frmSlideshow);
    animation->setStartValue(0);
    animation->setEndValue(ui->frmSlideshow->width());
    animation->setDuration(600);
    animation->start(QVariantAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);

    connect(animation, SIGNAL(valueChanged(QVariant)),
            this, SLOT(onValueChanged(QVariant)));
```

**SLOT** - onValueChanged()

```
void onValueChanged(const QVariant &value)
{
    int n = -value.toInt();
    int m = ui->frmSlideshow->width() + n;
    d->currImage->move(n, 0);
    d->nextImage->move(m, 0);
    this->repaint();
}

/** ui->frmSlideshow is the frame, on which images are sliding **/
```